# blue background in chrome on touch events

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

specs:
screen: Acer T272HUL 27"
computer: Intel NUC5PGYH
os: windows 10
application: Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 64 bit

I have some troubles with google chrome in kiosk mode. The user, from which I start chrome in kiosk mode, has some group policies. The custom user interface is set to: `C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe --kiosk --disk-cache-dir=null --incognito --disable-pinch file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/loading.html.`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9G24HGPrTao&feature=youtu.be

As you see in the video, I'm getting a weird blue background on some touches. In css I tried this code:

```
::-moz-selection {background: rgba(0,0,0,0);}
::selection {background: rgba(0,0,0,0);}
::-webkit-selection {background: rgba(0,0,0,0);}
* {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color:  rgba(0,0,0,0); 
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
     -khtml-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
}
```

to prevent it, but it doesnt' work.

I can't post the website or the code for reasons of secrecy.

Answer (score 1):

Try `*:focus`, and add `outline: none;` to your css also.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the square highlight box is drawn when a touchstart event converts to a click event. Then the background change occurs based on either a touchend or onmouseup event - try looking in dev tools (if you can access them) to see if any events are bound to the body.